# Items inside composite items are not listed on search

Tags: sxa, content-search, solr

In SXA Search we are not getting the results for items present inside composite components like Tab/Carousel components.

Does anyone have any suggestion that might help?

Comment: Are the templates of those items inheriting from `_Searchable` template and the location of those items are configured in the Associated Content field on the Settings item?

Comment: Please also check that those items are in the index. Keep in mind that the latest version of SXA is using their own indexes like `sitecore_sxa_master_index`.